# How to find number of lines of a Large CSV file without reading it - using R?

Tags: r

It is required to find the number of lines of a pretty big CSV file (about 100 GB) without reading it completely -- since it doesn't fit inside the RAM. What is the MOST OPTIMIZED way to achieve this in R ?

Edit:
I have already tried out the following

[reading a text file in R line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626637/reading-a-text-file-in-r-line-by-line)

[Read Large File line by line in R without header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711585/read-large-file-line-by-line-in-r-without-header)

But seems to be pretty slow - for just finding number of rows ...

Comment: Thanks mate ... But it seems to be very slow for large files ...

Comment: Answer depends somewhat on your operating system and if Windows, whether Rtools is installed?

Comment: The answers in the duplicate are missing a useful option: `R.utils::countLines()`.